# How to convert Eclipse template file to IntelliJ template file

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

How can I convert Eclipse template file to IntelliJ template file. I do not want to add plugin to use the Eclipse file. I want to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

Though not strictly respecting your question (no plugin), the built-in plugin Eclipse integration of IDEA 13 can import Eclipse templates quite accurately:

http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/01/intellij-idea-13-importing-code-formatter-settings-from-eclipse/

As stated in that post, the result cannot be 100% accurate as IDEA does not support all of the template options present in Eclipse (and the opposite might be true too).